# OpenERP engine modification

Tags: python, inheritance, module, odoo

Is it possible to inherit OpenERP engine classes? For example, report.rml_parse or osv.fields?
The purpose is behavior replacement of printing all reports.
How can I do this? Maybe there are some methods like this(it's just thoughts, nothing else):

```
from openerp.report import rml_parse

class my_parser(object):
    ...blah-blah-blah...

rml_parse = my_parser
```

Or something like this:

```
from openerp.report import rml_parse

class my_parser(rml_parse):
    ...blah-blah-blah...
```

Last variant perfectly works with report in same module, but it don't work with another modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is almost complete; after you have created `my_parser` you need to replace OpenERP's parser with it:

```
openerp.report.rml_parse = my_parser
```

Timing could be an issue if other modules grab a reference (aka "bind a name") to `openerp.report.rml_parse` before you replace it.